# How can echo the string in PHP to output variable “$_GET" and “[ ]"?

Tags: php

I have a script that read in a text file using foreach loop, but the string is unable to recognize "$_GET" or "[ ]" to display or to echo out the string. If the the echo works correctly then I can append the string output to another php file to execute, but I'm not able to make the string to echo appropriately. Please advice. Thx

```
<?php

$filename = "./client.txt";
echo $filename ."\n"."<br>" ;
$contents = file($filename);
foreach ($contents as $line) {
    $line = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $line);
    $str = " $$line=$_GET["$line"]; " ;
echo $str;
}

?>

 --------------------------------------
 Text file: client.txt
 DEPLOYMENT_ID
 CLINICAL_APP
 ZOO_MAX
 SVN_REPO

 ---------------------------------------
 Echo output should be:

 $DEPLOYMENT_ID=$_GET["DEPLOYMENT_ID"];
 $CLINICAL_APP=$_GET["CLINICAL_APP"];
 $ZOO_MAX=$_GET["ZOO_MAX"];
 $SVN_REPO=$_GET["SVN_REPO"];
```

Comment: Use single quote instead of double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `sprintf`

like `sprintf("$%s=\$_GET['%s']",$line,$line);`

Comment: Still not working, I get the same error and the $line still undefined. Please advice. thx

Comment: The actual error "Undefined variable: str in phploop2.php on line 13". Please advice. thx

Comment: I fixed the str variable and it seem to work. $str = sprintf("$%s=\$_GET['%s'];",$line,$line ." \n ");

Comment: However the display show single quote in the bracket. Is there a way to make the double quote show inside the bracket?

Right now it showing: $DEPLOYMENT_ID=$_GET['DEPLOYMENT_ID ']

How can we make as: $DEPLOYMENT_ID=$_GET[ "DEPLOYMENT_ID "] ?

Please advice. Thx

Comment: replace `$_GET['%s']` with `$_GET[\"%s\"]`, it will change single quotes to double

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to echoing it, use `'` single quote inside `GET` :

```
$str = " $$line=$_GET['" . $line . "'] " ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm getting this error "syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in phploop2.php on line 11". Please advices. Thx

Comment: Do the `$line` showing any output instead of undefined or empty value?